# How to filter the return value of a class that extends the list object

Tags: python

I have a class that extends the list object, seemed appropriate since it *is* a list, that class also has two boolean attributes that are meant to filter the return value.

I was able to populate the class calling self.append, the class is meant to receive a list dictionary and append an instance of a class that stores that dictionary's content; the class  stores a list of instances of a specific class, much like a vector in other languages.

Here's a sample code:

```
data = [
    { 'id': 0, 'attr1': True, 'attr2': False },
    { 'id': 1, 'attr1': False, 'attr2': True },
    { 'id': 2, 'attr1': False, 'attr2': False },
    { 'id': 3, 'attr1': True, 'attr2': True }
]

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.id = data['id']
        self.attr1 = data['attr1']
        self.attr2 = data['attr2']

class MyList(list):
    condition1 = True
    condition2 = True

    def __init__(self, data):
        for content in data:
            self.append(MyClass(content))
```

This actually works, meaning I get a list o *MyClasses* instances, now what I want to do is if I change the value of condition1 to False when I access the list it should filter the results like so:

```
my_list = MyList(data)
for item in my_list:
    print 'id', item.id, 'attr1', item.attr1, 'attr2', item.attr2
# >> id 0 attr1 True attr2 False
# >> id 1 attr1 False attr2 True
# >> id 2 attr1 False attr2 False
# >> id 3 attr1 True attr2 True

my_list.condition1 = False
# Now it should list only the instances of MyClass that has the attr1 set to False
for item in my_list:
    print 'id', item.id, 'attr1', item.attr1, 'attr2', item.attr2
# >> id 1 attr1 False attr2 True
# >> id 2 attr1 False attr2 False
```

I'm pretty new to Python so I'm not sure even if I can do this at all.

Comment: what is the purpose of the id in MyClass? BTW it is not working.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the code so it's more concise.
To answer your question the id in the MyClass in this example is purely aesthetic so it's easier to read the output from the iterations.

Comment: classes are used not as often as in other languages. Your problem would be a one-liner in python: `for item in filter(lambda n: n['attr1'] is False, data): print 'id', item['id'], '...'`

Comment: @Daniel I understand that I can filter the results outside the class like you suggested; I can even implement that logic in a method inside MyList. But is there any way I can filter the _output_ of the list as I first intended? Also what do you mean by classes are used not often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to override `__iter__`, for example:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.condition1 = True
        self.condition2 = True
        for content in data:
            self.append(MyClass(content))

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self[i] for i in range(len(self))
                if ((self.condition1 or self[i].attr1) and
                    (self.condition2 or self[i].attr2)))
```

Note that I have made e.g. `condition1` an instance, not class, attribute; I assume that you could have different instances of the class with different settings for those flags.

Also, you will have to implement `__eq__` on `MyClass` to use this for e.g. `my_class in my_list`, and you can simplify `MyClass.__init__` to:

```
def __init__(self, data):
    self.__dict__.update(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that worked, and thanks for the tip about instance attributes and the __dict__.update. ;)